# defining methods for template class

Tags: c++

I would like to achieve something like that:

```
template <class that, class has, class much, class genericizem>
class Generic{
// using all template stuff
     Generic &method(Generic &gen1, Generic &gen2);
};

// what I assume is the solution from vage things I've read

template <class that, class has, class much, class genericizem>
    using Gen = Generic<that,has,much,genericizem>;

// and no one wants to see the naive way of writing it.
Gen &Gen::method(Gen &gen1, Gen &gen2){
    return gen1;
}
```

I know that you cant template a namespace, so do I just write it the long way?

Comment: Please install and use a spellchecker. ;) That said, templates and overloaded function ease the way that you use things, but I don't understand how you intend to use your code. What is the calling syntax you want to achieve? Isn't all you need here a type alias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want, if I understand your question correctly, cannot be done as you are trying. Even if your `using Gen = ...` worked, you'd still need to write:

```
template <class that, class has, class much, class genericizem>
Gen<that,has,much,genericizem> &Gen<that,has,much,genericizem>::method(Gen &gen1, Gen &gen2){
```

becuase `Gen` is a template alias, atually quite equivalent to the original `Genric`.

Your member function can be defined as:

```
template <class that, class has, class much, class genericizem>
auto Generic<that,has,much,genericizem>::method(Generic &gen1, Generic &gen2) -> Generic&
{
    /* ... */
}
```

You don't need to repeat all the template arguments every time you refer to `Generic`, because a plain `Generic` stands for the class to be instantiated. This is calledd the *injected class name*.

But note that syntactically the return type is not inside the class scope, so you cannot use the injected class name there. Instead, you can use `auto` and a trailing return type.

Comment: i guess you cant have code without writing(or copy pasting). auto is good thou, and i also thought i had to write arguments to the arguments so that's a future bug fixed. thanks!.

Comment: @rustypaper: Sometimes being explicit is worth a bit of copy/pasting. If they are really cumbersome you could use macros, but I would consider that a last resort.

Comment: in case you wonder, i spent 2 hours to find a work around 20 min of work.